# Terminology for a several variables function whose value only depends on one variable?

Tags: calculus, functions, reference-request, notation, terminology

Is there terminology for a function formally defined to depend on several variables whose values only depend on a subset of the variables?

For example,
$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} \,, \quad f: (x,y) \mapsto \sin x \,,$$
$$g: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R} \,, \quad g:(x,y,z,u) \mapsto 4z^2 \,,$$
both functions whose value are only affected by one variable. (E.g. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \equiv 0$, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} \equiv 0$.)

Are there any special names for those functions?

Comment: If it depends solely on one variable, then how can it be a several-variables function?

Comment: Maybe he is implying that his function $f$ is defined in a space of dimension $>1$, even though it really only depends on one variable?

Comment: Not really a name, but one way to describe such a function is to note that it *factors through* a space of smaller dimension. For example, $g$ factors as $\mathbb{R}^4 \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{\bar{g}} \mathbb{R}$, where $\pi(x,y,z,u) = z$ and $\bar{g}(v) = 4v^2$.